# React custom hook not working for fetch POST method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

Creating custom hooks for `POST` method in `fetch()`. Unfortunately, the API is not calling with in the `useCallBack()` Is there anything missing with in the code?

**usePostQuery.js**

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

const usePostQuery = (url, data) => {
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const callPost = useCallback(
    async (data) => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);

        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            title: data.message,
            userId: 5
          })
        });

        console.log("---------response---------");
        console.log(response);
        const jsonResult = await response.json();

        setResponseData(jsonResult);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    },
    [url]
  );

  return { responseData, loading, error, callPost };
};

export default usePostQuery;
```

[image: Edit determined-danny-7c5nni]

The Post method should call when click on a button or submit form.

Comment: Can you show where you call `callPost`? EDIT: the sandbox doesn't call it either, so that appears to be the problem. When do you want to call it?

Comment: @NicholasTower I just need to post when a form submit or click button

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code sandbox, you're never actually invoking `callPost`. You'd need to do something like this:

```
const { responseData, loading, error, callPost } = usePostQuery(
  "https://dummyjson.com/posts/add",
  message
);

// add this part: useEffect which invokes callPost
useEffect(() => {
  callPost({ message: "hello" });
}, [callPost]);
```

When I do that, I get the response logs in the console:

```
---------response--------- 
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://dummyjson.com/posts/add", 
  redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true…}
```

Just a reminder, you'd also need to add the import for `useEffect` at the top of your App.js:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
```

forked code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-meadow-3dp65m?file=/src/App.js